# Unable to set a cookie in codeigniter 4 before redirection

Tags: redirect, cookies, setcookie, codeigniter-4

I am working on a sign in form where I am setting remember-me token. I am facing a issue that is, Without redirection on admin dashboard, the cookie is setting properly. But when I am redirecting it on dashboard it's not working.

this is what i am doing for setting cookie:

```
//generating cookie value
$cookie = hash('gost',rand());
set_cookie('OD_AU',$cookie,86400*30,$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],'/');
```

and for redirection:

```
return redirect()->to('/site-management');
```

Answer (score 2):

A more dynamic solution would be appending `->withCookies()` to the redirect:

`return redirect()->to('/site-management')->withCookies();`

[Source](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=redirect#redirect)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the cookie in the return function chain like this:

`return redirect()->to('/site-management')->setCookie('OD_AU', $cookie, 86400*30);`